# MySql Delete records from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete **most** of the records associated with a particular parent record in MySql.  I'm not using cascading deletes because there's a linked record in the chain that I don't want to delete.

Basically I have 4 tables with one parent and three sets of child records. At a high level, what I want to do should look like this:

```sql
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
START TRANSACTION; 
DELETE FROM message_content WHERE campaign_id=3; 
DELETE FROM targets WHERE campaign_id=3; 
DELETE FROM imports WHERE campaign_id=3; 
DELETE FROM campaigns WHERE id=3; 
COMMIT;
```

However, when I run that code, I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'START TRANSACTION; DELETE FROM message_content WHERE campaign_id=3; DELETE FROM ' at line 1
```

Reading through other questions on Stack Overflow, most of them recommend using JOINs to make this work; this makes sense but I'm struggling to figure out the syntax for this as all of the examples use the same key for all tables and for my case, the campaigns table uses a different key.

What should my code look like? Is this correct?

```sql
DELETE campaigns, message_content, targets, imports 
FROM campaigns
INNER JOIN message_content ON campaigns.id=message_content.campaign_id 
INNER JOIN targets ON campaigns.id=targets.campaign_id
INNER JOIN imports ON campaigns.id=imports.campaign_id
WHERE campaigns.id=3;
```

When I try a version of the code in a SELECT query (I'm a little nervous to start deleting things) I get no results set when there should be some.

Can someone please help me with the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Did you check if there are any invisible characters other then the (platform dependent) newline sequence between `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` 
and `START TRANSACTION;` that may cause this?

Comment: How do you run this code? To me it seems as if ; was not recognised as statement terminator and the whole script is considered a single statement. This would result in the error message you described.

Comment: I'm executing this inside of a Firebase Function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#multiple-statement-queries:

Support for multiple statements is disabled for security reasons (it allows for SQL injection attacks if values are not properly escaped). To use this feature you have to enable it for your connection:

```js
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

With that setting in place, it worked.